# get_post_custom_values not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have made a custom template to show the posts in "Products" category in a single page.I have some custom fields.I need to show the values of the custom fields in the page. I have used the get_post_custom_values as the following but i get an error as

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\SampleSite\wp-content\themes\TwentyElevenChildTheme\products.php on line 11
```

The code for products.php is as follows.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Product Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">
   <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=4&showposts=10"); while($recent->have_posts()) :$recent->the_post();?>
   <?php $key_values = get_post_custom_values("Description"); ?>
   <?php foreach($key_values as $key => $value )?>
   <?php echo  "$key  => $value("Description") <br />";?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am not getting what the error is.Someone please help in this

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_custom_values()` returns **null** if the key does not exist. *Ref: wp-includes/.post.php:1892*

You can cast the returned value to an array to make sure you're always dealing with an array and avoid that warning:

```
<?php $key_values = (array) get_post_custom_values("Description"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use `get_post_meta`? I use it in my website and it is working as expected.